# Why am I getting NaN for this variable?

Tags: javascript

Anyone know why the bigNumberB variable is returning Not a number? I'm new to java and messing around with functions and I can't see what I'm doing wrong here but I'm sure its something simple. Thanks, I am getting 24, 24, NaN

```
function mathEquation(moja, mbili, tatu, tano) {  
var value = moja * mbili * tatu * tano;  
console.log(value);  
}

mathEquation(1, 2, 3, 4);

function inceptEquation(sita, tisa) {  
var bigNumber = mathEquation(1, 2, 3, 4);  
console.log(bigNumber);  
var bigNumberB = sita + tisa + bigNumber;  
console.log(bigNumberB);  
}

inceptEquation(11, 23);
```

Comment: `mathEquation` prints a value, but it doesn’t return a value.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning anything from `mathEquation`

```
function mathEquation(moja, mbili, tatu, tano) {  
  var value = moja * mbili * tatu * tano;  
  console.log(value);  
  return value; // <- return the value here
}
```

Without returning a value, you are trying to add `11 + 23 + undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning the sum of value in `mathEquation`. By default a function with no explicit return value will return `undefined`. So essentially you're doing this in `inceptEquation`:

```
11 + 23 + undefined;
```

Adding undefined to any number will result in `NaN`.

Instead just return the sum as so. There's no need for the `value` if it's not being used anywhere else in the function:

```
function mathEquation(moja, mbili, tatu, tano) {  
  return moja * mbili * tatu * tano;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to change the `console.log()`s to `return()`s. Here is the simple version:

```
function multiplication(x, y, z, c) {
  var value = x * y * z * c;
  return(value);
}

console.log(multiplication(1, 2, 3, 4));

function addition(x, y) {
  multiplication(1, 2, 3, 4);
  return(x + y + multiplication(1, 2, 3, 4));
}

console.log(addition(11, 23));
```

Hopefully this is what you were expecting!